# Rails 3, proper way to do partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Have the following code throwing an error. I've always just jury-rigged something before but want to learn the proper way. Is the proper way to pass the local variables? Say you also have an instance variable you want to use in the partial?

```
@users is an array of user emails
<% @users.each do |email| %>
   <%= render :partial => 'user/foobar' %>
<% end %>

user/foobar
<div id="user_<%= email %>>
   <div><%= email %></div>
</div>
```

EDIT: also will want to use the partial in a js file after adding an email address. Would I set the instance after create to @user or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `each`. You can use the `:collection` option:

```
<%= render :partial => "user/foobar", :collection => @users %>
```

In `user/_foobar.html.erb` partial (below, the automatically-created local variable `foobar` will contain the current instance of an item from the `@users` collection):

```
<div id="user_<%= foobar %>>
   <div><%= user %></div>
</div>
```

The local variable is named after the name of the partial. See [guide here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections).

Comment: Quick question, if I then had a js file that wanted to use the partial after an action (say adding a user) would I set an instance variable to @user or something else?

Comment: There was a mistake in the code, I have fixed it. Also added a link to the Rails guide.

Comment: Ideally, you would pass a local variable to the partial and not access an instance variable like `@user` inside the partial. That way your partial is not dependent so much on code outside the partial.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
render :partial => 'user/foobar', :locals => {:email => email }
```

this passes-in your local variable 'email' as the symbol :email